# Adding and Deleting draggable rectangles on the Image and Saving to a file

Tags: matlab

I have written the following code through which I am loading an Image using a load button and then I draw different rectangles on the image using draw button and save them to a text file.

I have made 3 buttons on my Image.

1.load(it loads the image on the GUI)
2.Draw (by pressing it user would be able to draw draggable rectangles on the Image.
3.Save(Using this button user would be able to save all the rectangles in the text file).

**Load**

```
function loadButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to loadButton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
I=imread('http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/corporate2/images/width/live/p0/0l/3r/p00l3rnt.jpg/624');
imshow(I);
rectangles=cell(1,1);
count=0;
handles.rectangles=rectangles;
handles.count=count;
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

**Draw**

```
function drawButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to drawButton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
rectangles=handles.rectangles;
count=handles.count;
count=count+1;
h=imrect;
rectangles{count,1}=h;
handles.count=count;
handles.rectangles=rectangles;
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

**Save**

```
function saveButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to saveButton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
rectangles=handles.rectangles;
for i=1:length(rectangles)
   dlmwrite('P:\bla.txt',rectangles{i}.getPosition,'-append','delimiter',' ','newline','pc');
end
```

The above code works well with the following problem.If I delete a rectangle(s)  then following error comes up?

```
**Invalid or deleted object**.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saving, you should check if your rectangles are valid handle objects (i.e. not deleted):

```
function saveButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
        rectangles=handles.rectangles;
        delete('P:\bla.txt');
        fclose(fopen('P:\bla.txt', 'w')); % To be able to append
        for k=1:length(rectangles)
                if isvalid(rectangles{k})
                        dlmwrite( ...
                           'P:\bla.txt', rectangles{k}.getPosition, ...
                           '-append',                               ...
                           'delimiter', ' ',                        ...
                           'newline', 'pc'                          ...
                        );
                end;
        end;
```

Unrelated to the issue, but one day might save you hours of hair-pulling: don't use `i` as variable, because it's the imaginary unit in MATLAB.

Comment: The code does NOT run since ishandle is returning 0 always.So I used negation inside the if condition.But then same error came up when I deleted a rectangle "deleted object"

Comment: I don't have the image toolbox to test, but the idea should be correct. Can you try with `isvalid` instead? (just in case is an object that inherits `handle` class)

Comment: I am afraid that this idea would work only if I catch event that gets fired on deleting the rectangles.

Comment: @NaseerAhmed Sorry for insisting, but did you try using `isvalid` instead of `ishandle`? I don't see any callback in help that would be called on deletion, only on position change.

Comment: isvalid is not there in matlab 2016.

Comment: @NaseerAhmed Wow, that's weird, since is a fundamental method of handle classes: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.isvalid.html Anyways, there is one more test function that you can use `isgraphics`. Let me know if neither work, and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: That worked ok .you are right.The intellisense was not showing that function but when I used that function it got right.Please also tell me how to change the color and pixel size of the draggable rectangles I am creating using imrect?

Comment: Another query is that since when I delete a rectangle and want to save the new set of rectangles to the file, it appends the new rectangles to the existing file.Is there some way I could recreate that file each time I click the save button since in this way I would not be appending to the existing file?

Comment: @NaseerAhmed: remove the `'-append'` option from your `dmlwrite` function call.

Comment: But since I am writing a bunch of rectangles so when I removed the -append tag it did not write all the rectangles to a file.It only wrote the last rectangle found at the last iteration?

Comment: You are right, I missed that. You can just delete the file before entering the `for` loop, with `delete('P:\bla.txt');` and recreate it again: `fclose(fopen('P:\bla.txt', 'w'))`.

Comment: thanks very much indeed and one thing which I asked you before was how would I change the style like color and pixel width of rectangles that I am drawing using imrect?